# Event vs EventHandler

Tags: c#, events, eventhandler

I read a lot of materials but I still did not understand, can someone explain me, please?

What do I know:

Declare an event:

```
public event MyEvent myEvent;
```

Vs.

declare EventHandler:

```
public EventHandler MyEventHandler;
```

While EventHandler is a keyword in .NET:

```
public delegate void EventHandler (Send object, EventArgs e);
```

So, EventHandler is a delegate and not an event, since it is not used in the keyword 'event'?

And when should I use 'Event' and when 'EventHandler'?

Comment: The `event` is the thing that RAISES an event, to which something will subscribe. The `EventHandler` is the thing that HANDLES an event - i.e. it specifies the method that is used to subscribe to the event.

Comment: Exposing a *field* `public EventHandler MyEventHandler;` is a bad practice; put an *event* `public event MyEvent myEvent;` which is specially designed for this purpose (and has *backing* `EventHandler` field)

Comment: It's all explained quite well here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/

Comment: An event has a *type*, it describes what arguments should be passed when the event is raised and what parameters the event handler must have to be compatible with the event  The type is described by a delegate declaration.  EventHandler is one such declaration (not a keyword), provided by the framework.  It dictates that an event handler must have 2 arguments, everybody names them sender and e.  MyEvent is another, provided by you, we can't see it.  It is a good idea to use the framework declaration, it makes your code easy to read.

Comment: @HansPassant: Thanks! starting to understand. so EventHandler is a specific delegate that provided by the framework? and if I'm writing public EventHandler MyEventHandler; I actually declared a simple delegate. and if I writing public event EventHandler MyEventHandler; I just declared a simple event object?

Comment: You are getting closer.  You declared a simple event, that's all.  Not a delegate, that one came from the framework.  An event behaves a lot like a property.  You use a property to limit access to a private field, external code must use the get and set accessor.  An event similarly limits access to a private delegate object, external code can only add and remove an event handler.  External code can't raise the event, it can't force the delegate object to null and it can't unsubscribe a handler registered by other code.  Limiting access is a good thing.

Comment: "While EventHandler is a keyword in .NET:" - no it is not. In your code `MyEvent` and `EventHandler` are both delegate Types, `MyEventHandler` is a delegate instance.

Comment: The trick to understand the `event` keyword is that it actually declares a delegate-based property. So `myEvent` is an encapsulated delegate instance.

Answer (score 23):

Ah, the event vs. delegate question. I remember having that question as well...

So, suppose you're making a class called "Cat" and you want to let people know when your cat is hungry. You could do that in one of two ways: by exposing a delegate on the Cat class or by exposing an event.

You can think of a delegate as a pointer to a function (or method). So let's say there's a class called "Person" that has a method called `FeedCat(Cat cat)`.

**The delegate way**

---

If your cat is exposing a delegate called `HungryDelegate`, the person can point the delegate to their `FeedCat` method, so that when the cat is hungry, it has a way to call the `FeedCat` method on the person.

The problem here is, only one person can feed the cat. Suppose you want multiple people to be able to feed the cat. People can be busy doing other things, so it's important for the cat to be able to tell multiple people that it's hungry. That way, people get notified of this, and they can check up on the cat when they have a chance, see if someone already fed the cat, and feed it if not.

**Events to the rescue:**

---

An event is basically a list of delegates (of a certain type). If you expose a `Hungry` event on your "Cat" class, multiple people can ADD *pointers* (delegates) to their `FeedCat` methods.

They can also remove the pointers (delegates) to their `FeedCat` methods if they like. Let's say a person moved out, and their sister is now taking care of the cat. The person can remove their delegate for their own `FeedCat` function from the cat, so that they no longer get notified that the darn cat is hungry.

**Events vs. multicast delegates?**

---

Technically, in order to be able to provide multiple delegates, you could use the so called MultiCastDelegates instead of events. They are composite delegates (a linked list of delegates). The problem there is, everyone can mess with them from the outside. An evil person could remove everyone else's "FeedCat" delegates, and the poor cat would starve (or would have to learn to hunt).

The important thing when using events is that the person cannot see other people's delegates that are added to the event, and *in principle* it can't remove them or interact with them.

Comment: Listener = Delegate, Observer = Event

Answer (score 12):

Exposing a (`public`) *field*

```
 public EventHandler MyEventHandler;
```

is a *bad practice*: one can easily *ruin* the code with a small typo:

```
 MyClass demo = new MyClass();

 demo.MyEventHandler += MyMethod;

 ...

 // Can you see the error? = instead of correct += ?
 // MyMethod will not be called since this assignment 
 demo.MyEventHandler = MyReaction;
```

That's why you should use *event* which has been specially desinged for this

```
 public event EventHandler MyEventHandler;
```

if we try the previous `demo` we'll get **compile time error**:

```
 MyClass demo = new MyClass();

 ...

 demo.MyEventHandler = MyReaction; // <- doesn't compile, insist on +=
```

In very rare cases you may want explicit delegate-based fields, but these field should be concealed, say, be `private`, not `public`:

```
// We don't expose the field
private EventHandler m_MyEventHandler;

// ... But event:
public event EventHandler MyEventHandler {
  add {
    //TODO: extra logic on += operation

    m_MyEventHandler += value;
  }
  remove {
    //TODO: extra logic on -= operation

    m_MyEventHandler -= value;
  }  
}
```

Comment: 3rd code fragment (after "That's why you should use _event_ which has been specially desinged for this") should probably be
`public event EventHandler MyEventHandler;`
i.e. `event` keyword should be added (otherwise it is identical to the 1st code fragment).

Answer (score 1):

## DELEGATES, EVENTS(EVENT HANDLERS/EVENT LISTENERS), CONCEPTS(MULTICASTING/BROADCASTING), ACTION & FUNC

This will be a long one but its the simplest explanation, the problem this is such a nuisance of a topic is because people are just using different words to explain the same thing

First of all, you should know a few things

### DELEGATES: It's nothing but a list of methods, why create a list? because when your code is being executed, that list is taken and every method there is executed one by one, just don't listen to textbook definitions take this and you will be all right

also called :

- a pointer to a function
- a wrapper for a method that can send and receive methods just like a variable

to create a delegate you go

```
[[access modifier] delegate [return type] [delegate name]([parameters])]

example: public delegate int demo(int a);
```

now to execute all these methods stored in a list called delegate, you go

```
1. demo.invoke(a);
2. demo(a);   ..... both are valid
```

using the dot and explicitly saying invoke shines in async programming where you use beginInvoke, but that is out of the scope of this topic

there is one more thing called "Creating an object of the delegate/instantiate Delegate" which is pretty much as it sounds but just to avoid confusion it goes like (for the above example )

```
example : demo del = new demo(); (or) Public demo del = null;
```

to add any method to the list called delegate you go += and you also need to remove it once the "requirements of the methods are met" you go -=

(requirements of the methods are met mean you no longer need the method to be active or aka "listening") if you don't remove it, it could cause a "memory leak" meaning your computers ram will be eaten alive, technically allocated memory will not be released

example: say there is a method

```
public int calculate (int c)

to add this method to delegate you go

1.  del = calculate;
2.  del += calculate; .... all are valid

to remove 

del -= calculate
```

first of all notice the similarities between the delegate and the method, the return type(output) and the input/parameters are the same, and that is a rule you just cannot add any random or a bunch of methods in a delegate it needs to follow the input-output rule

now  why are there 2 different ways to do one thing, the only thing different is the assignment operators (+, =), this introduces a new topic called

### EVENTS

which is nothing but a constrained version of a Delegate, It's still a List of methods don't confuse when people explain these terminologies, they change the name, so stick with this to understand

what is the constraint? you cannot do this `del = calculate;`
what's the harm in it, say a bunch of methods are added to the Delegate(List), you do that  all are wiped out and only a single method "calculate" remains, so to prevent that Events are used,
Event Syntax

Public Event demo del = null;

One more thing you cannot do with events is invoke the delegate directly like `demo.invoke` since its public it can be accessed and invoked but with events, it can't

now you just add the methods to the event (a special type of delegate)

when to use an event vs a delegate, depends on your situation but pragmatically events are popular

few more keywords

MULTICASTING: nothing but adding more than one method to a delegate
BROADCASTING: adding more than one method to an event

PUBLISHER: the one that executes the method (term used in broadcasting), only a single entity
SUBSCRIBER: The methods that are being executed, can be multiple

LISTENER: the same thing as a subscriber but the term is used in multicasting

EVENT HANDLER: same thing as a subscriber/event listener so what the difference? it's basically the same thing, some say an eventlistener detect for the event to occur and the event handler "handles" or execute the code, ITS THE SAME THING PRACTICALLY!

action and func are just delegates that have been created and instantiated so 2 lines of code in a word, the difference is just in return types

ACTION: does not return anything while taking 0 or more than 1 input

FUNC: returns one thing and takes in parameters

if you don't do good with reading here is the best video on this topic

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLFt_AvWsXl0dliMtpZC8Qd_ru26785Ih_